# IntelliJ Idea: configure build for stub

Tags: java, intellij-idea, builder

Suppose, we don't have access to some needed server while debugging program on our machine. So we need a stub. But then every time i want make build without stub i need to comment my stub code and uncomment actual code, so it looks dirty. It would be nice if i can configure builds somehow to avoid this commenting/uncommenting. I haven't figured out any good decision.

For example, some code

```
public class SingeFormatServiceClient {
      public static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://creditregistry.ru/2010/webservice/SingleFormatService", "SingleFormatService");

      public SingleFormatService Connect(){
          URL wsdlURL = SingleFormatService_Service.WSDL_LOCATION;

          SingleFormatService_Service ss = new SingleFormatService_Service(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
          return ss.getSingleFormatServiceHttpPort();
      }

      public SingleFormatService Connect(){
          return new SingleFormatServiceStub();
     }
}
```

So first function is actual, second is stub. May be there is a way not to comment, but just saying to builder that now i want make build with first function, and now - with second?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use system property to choose which implementation?

Comment: Thomas, you mean JVM argument? That's what i'm doing now, but i hope there is more elegant ways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty()` to instantiate an implementation. For example:

```
SingleFormatService service = (SingleFormatService) Class.forName(
    System.getProperty("single_format_service_class",
    "your.comp.SingleFormatServiceStub")).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Your implementation must provide non-arg constructor. In your jvm argument, specify the working class, i.e.

```
-Dsingle_format_service_class=your.comp.SingleFormatServiceActual
```

In intellij idea, you could specify several run configurations using different jvm args.

NB. IMO many libraries use that way. Hibernate uses `hibernate.cache.provider_class` to choose which cache provider implementation to use.